# What does ./configure --disable-zebra in the Quagga suite stand for?

Tags: linux, routing, quagga

I am currently configuring Quagga. Quagga is an routing suite for Linux. 
I was suggested to use --disable-zebra when configuring Quagga (./configure --disable-zebra). Does anyone exactly know what this command does?

(Quagga homepage: http://www.quagga.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zebra appears to be the daemon which redistributes routes between protocols within the routing suite, amongst other things. More details on what zebra does can be found [here](http://www.quagga.net/docs/docs-info.php#SEC32). --disable zebra will install quagga without zebra.

Answer (score 2):

./configure --disable-zebra wont build zebra daemon

"zebra is an IP routing manager. It provides kernel routing table updates, interface lookups, and redistribution of routes between different routing protocols." from http://www.quagga.net/docs/docs-info.php#SEC32